# Solution: get report faster from database with big data

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I use oracle database. I have many table with data very big (300-500 million record).

I use query statement have join many table together. I set index for table but get report very slow.

Please, help me solution when working with big data.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question actually has no information that anyone can use to help you.

Comment: Flagging to close, there is not even close to enough information to answer. What is your non performing query, what does your schema look like, what sort of indexes are present?

Comment: Thanks, I need solution when create report from big data (index,partition,...). Query statement faster.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to have all the data at once?

Try creating a table that stores just the information you need for the report, and run a query once a day (or few hours) to update the table. You can also use Sql Server Integration Services, although I have not tried SSIS with Oracle myself.

I agree with the other users, you really need to give more info on the problem.